# spring data jdbc. Can't add custom converter for enum

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I want to have enum as a field for my entity.

My application is look like:

Spring boot version

```
plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2' apply false
```

repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, UUID> {
 ...
```

entity:

```
@Table("my_entity")
public class MyEntity{
   ...
   private FileType fileType;
  // get + set
}
```

enum declaration:

```
public enum FileType {
    TYPE_1(1),
    TYPE_2(2);

    int databaseId;

    public static FileType byDatabaseId(Integer databaseId){
        return Arrays.stream(values()).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
    FileType(int databaseId) {
        this.databaseId = databaseId;
    }

    public int getDatabaseId() {
        return databaseId;
    }
}
```

**My attempt:**

I've found following answer and try to follow it : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53296199/2674303

So I've added bean

```
@Bean
public JdbcCustomConversions jdbcCustomConversions() {
    return new JdbcCustomConversions(asList(new DatabaseIdToFileTypeConverter(), new FileTypeToDatabaseIdConverter()));
}
```

converters:

```
@WritingConverter
public class FileTypeToDatabaseIdConverter implements Converter<FileType, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer convert(FileType source) {
        return source.getDatabaseId();
    }
}

@ReadingConverter
public class DatabaseIdToFileTypeConverter implements Converter<Integer, FileType> {
    @Override
    public FileType convert(Integer databaseId) {
        return FileType.byDatabaseId(databaseId);
    }
}
```

But I see error:

> The bean 'jdbcCustomConversions', defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class],
> could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been
> defined in my.pack.Main and overriding is disabled.

I've tried to rename method `jdbcCustomConversions()` to `myJdbcCustomConversions()`. It helped to avoid error above but converter is not invoked during entity persistence and I see another error that application tries to save String but database type is bigint.

```
20:39:10.689  DEBUG  [main] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils: JDBC getParameterType call failed - using fallback method instead: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "file_type" is of type bigint but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 174
```

I also tried to use the latest(currently) version of spring boot:

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2' apply false
```

But it didn't help.

What have I missed ?
How can I map enum to integer column properly ?

**P.S.**

I use following code for testing:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJdbcAuditing
@EnableScheduling
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        MyEntityRepositoryrepository = applicationContext.getBean(MyEntityRepository.class);
        MyEntity entity =  new MyEntity();
        ...
        entity.setFileType(FileType.TYPE_2);
        repository.save(entity);
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.getConfiguration()
                .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT)
                .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
                .setSkipNullEnabled(true)
                .setFieldAccessLevel(PRIVATE);
        return mapper;
    }


    @Bean
    public AbstractJdbcConfiguration jdbcConfiguration() {
        return new MySpringBootJdbcConfiguration();
    }
    @Configuration
    static class MySpringBootJdbcConfiguration extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {
        @Override
        protected List<?> userConverters() {
            return asList(new DatabaseIdToFileTypeConverter(), new FileTypeToDatabaseIdConverter());
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

My code is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJdbcAuditing
@EnableScheduling
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        MyEntityRepositoryrepository = applicationContext.getBean(MyEntityRepository.class);
        MyEntity entity =  new MyEntity();
        ...
        entity.setFileType(FileType.TYPE_2);
        repository.save(entity);
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.getConfiguration()
                .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT)
                .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
                .setSkipNullEnabled(true)
                .setFieldAccessLevel(PRIVATE);
        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractJdbcConfiguration jdbcConfiguration() {
        return new MySpringBootJdbcConfiguration();
    }

    @Configuration
    static class MySpringBootJdbcConfiguration extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {
        @Override
        protected List<?> userConverters() {
            return asList(new DatabaseIdToFileTypeConverter(), new FileTypeToDatabaseIdConverter());
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcConverter jdbcConverter(JdbcMappingContext mappingContext,
                                           NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations,
                                           @Lazy RelationResolver relationResolver,
                                           JdbcCustomConversions conversions,
                                           Dialect dialect) {

            JdbcArrayColumns arrayColumns = dialect instanceof JdbcDialect ? ((JdbcDialect) dialect).getArraySupport()
                    : JdbcArrayColumns.DefaultSupport.INSTANCE;
            DefaultJdbcTypeFactory jdbcTypeFactory = new DefaultJdbcTypeFactory(operations.getJdbcOperations(),
                    arrayColumns);

            return new MyJdbcConverter(
                    mappingContext,
                    relationResolver,
                    conversions,
                    jdbcTypeFactory,
                    dialect.getIdentifierProcessing()
            );
        }
    }

    static class MyJdbcConverter extends BasicJdbcConverter {
        MyJdbcConverter(
                MappingContext<? extends RelationalPersistentEntity<?>, ? extends RelationalPersistentProperty> context,
                RelationResolver relationResolver,
                CustomConversions conversions,
                JdbcTypeFactory typeFactory,
                IdentifierProcessing identifierProcessing) {
            super(context, relationResolver, conversions, typeFactory, identifierProcessing);
        }

        @Override
        public int getSqlType(RelationalPersistentProperty property) {
            if (FileType.class.equals(property.getActualType())) {
                return Types.BIGINT;
            } else {
                return super.getSqlType(property);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnType(RelationalPersistentProperty property) {
            if (FileType.class.equals(property.getActualType())) {
                return Long.class;
            } else {
                return super.getColumnType(property);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I experience error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot convert an instance of java.lang.String to type long
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.cannotCastException(PgPreparedStatement.java:925)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.castToLong(PgPreparedStatement.java:810)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setObject(PgPreparedStatement.java:561)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setObject(PgPreparedStatement.java:931)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:414)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:146)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.setValues(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:241)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "TYPE_2"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.castToLong(PgPreparedStatement.java:792)
    ... 59 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```java
@Bean
public AbstractJdbcConfiguration jdbcConfiguration() {
    return new MySpringBootJdbcConfiguration();
}

@Configuration
static class MySpringBootJdbcConfiguration extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected List<?> userConverters() {
        return List.of(new DatabaseIdToFileTypeConverter(), new FileTypeToDatabaseIdConverter());
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

Spring complains that `JdbcCustomConversions` in auto-configuration class is already defined (by your bean) and you don't have bean overriding enabled.

`JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration` has changed a few times, in Spring 2.6.2 it has:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(AbstractJdbcConfiguration.class)
static class SpringBootJdbcConfiguration extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {

}
```

In turn, `AbstractJdbcConfiguration` has:

```java
@Bean
public JdbcCustomConversions jdbcCustomConversions() {

    try {

        Dialect dialect = applicationContext.getBean(Dialect.class);
        SimpleTypeHolder simpleTypeHolder = dialect.simpleTypes().isEmpty() ? JdbcSimpleTypes.HOLDER
                : new SimpleTypeHolder(dialect.simpleTypes(), JdbcSimpleTypes.HOLDER);

        return new JdbcCustomConversions(
                CustomConversions.StoreConversions.of(simpleTypeHolder, storeConverters(dialect)), userConverters());

    } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException exception) {

        LOG.warn("No dialect found. CustomConversions will be configured without dialect specific conversions.");

        return new JdbcCustomConversions();
    }
}
```

As you can see, `JdbcCustomConversions` is not conditional in any way, so defining your own caused a conflict. Fortunately, it provides an extension point `userConverters()` which can be overriden to provide your own converters.

**Update**

As discussed in comments:

- `FileType.byDatabaseId` is broken - it ignores its input param
- as the column type in db is BIGINT, your converters must convert from Long, not from Integer, this addresses read queries
- for writes, there is an open bug https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/629 There is a hardcoded assumption that Enums are converted to Strings, and only Enum -> String converters are checked.
  As we want to convert to Long, we need to make amendments to `BasicJdbcConverter` by subclassing it and registering subclassed converter with as a `@Bean`.

You need to override two methods

- `public int getSqlType(RelationalPersistentProperty property)`
- `public Class<?> getColumnType(RelationalPersistentProperty property)`

I hardcoded the Enum type and corresponding column types, but you may want to get more fancy with that.

```java
@Bean
public AbstractJdbcConfiguration jdbcConfiguration() {
    return new MySpringBootJdbcConfiguration();
}

@Configuration
static class MySpringBootJdbcConfiguration extends AbstractJdbcConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected List<?> userConverters() {
        return List.of(new DatabaseIdToFileTypeConverter(), new FileTypeToDatabaseIdConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcConverter jdbcConverter(JdbcMappingContext mappingContext,
                                       NamedParameterJdbcOperations operations,
                                       @Lazy RelationResolver relationResolver,
                                       JdbcCustomConversions conversions,
                                       Dialect dialect) {

        JdbcArrayColumns arrayColumns = dialect instanceof JdbcDialect ? ((JdbcDialect) dialect).getArraySupport()
                : JdbcArrayColumns.DefaultSupport.INSTANCE;
        DefaultJdbcTypeFactory jdbcTypeFactory = new DefaultJdbcTypeFactory(operations.getJdbcOperations(),
                arrayColumns);

        return new MyJdbcConverter(
                mappingContext,
                relationResolver,
                conversions,
                jdbcTypeFactory,
                dialect.getIdentifierProcessing()
        );
    }
}

static class MyJdbcConverter extends BasicJdbcConverter {
    MyJdbcConverter(
            MappingContext<? extends RelationalPersistentEntity<?>, ? extends RelationalPersistentProperty> context,
            RelationResolver relationResolver,
            CustomConversions conversions,
            JdbcTypeFactory typeFactory,
            IdentifierProcessing identifierProcessing) {
        super(context, relationResolver, conversions, typeFactory, identifierProcessing);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSqlType(RelationalPersistentProperty property) {
        if (FileType.class.equals(property.getActualType())) {
            return Types.BIGINT;
        } else {
            return super.getSqlType(property);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnType(RelationalPersistentProperty property) {
        if (FileType.class.equals(property.getActualType())) {
            return Long.class;
        } else {
            return super.getColumnType(property);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: During startup I see error: Parameter 0 of method setMappingContext in org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.RelationalMappingContext' that could not be found.

Comment: See update - I added `@Configuration` on `MySpringBootJdbcConfiguration` (so that Spring uses beans defined in it) - similarly `SpringBootJdbcConfiguration` was annotated with `@Configuration`

Comment: than you!  I see another issue now but I think it is not related to current topic... will let you know when I make sure that it work

Comment: Eventually It is started but I still see the same error:
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "file_type" is of type bigint but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 141

It is for spring boot 2.6.2

Comment: Also added a bit more details to the question. Maybe it will become clearer

Comment: Is it not https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/629 ?

Comment: Yes and no. You have BIGINT column in your database, so you should be converting from Longs, not Integers. This solves the read part - it will work fine. For saves, I get same error as you - I believe you found the correct bug report. I think you can easily override `converter.getSqlType` and `converter.getColumnType` in `BasicJdbcConverter` and get writes running as well.

Comment: could you provide a bit more details ?

Comment: thank you for your update. For now it workd but it doesn't use my converter. It uses enum ordinal value
method getColumnType is invoked

Comment: Works fine for me - declared converters are launched and FileType enum is transformed to Long, which is cuccessfully saved in bigint column.

Comment: I converted to int - let me try bigint

Comment: Your error `ERROR: column "file_type" is of type bigint` shows you have BigInt on DB side. You need Long in Java

Comment: I've changed type in the database to int. But let me try Bigint + Long insted of int + Integer

Comment: could you please take a look. I've updated the topic with actual code

Comment: Your error relates to `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "CONTACT_TO_GROUP"` There is no `CONTACT_TO_GROUP` in your question.

Comment: sorry - corrected error text  to be consistent. It was anonymized.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier - my FileTypeToDatabaseIdConverter is not invoked during persistence. And Some other converter is invoked whicj converts from enum to String

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241281/discussion-between-lesiak-and-gstackoverflow).